# How accurate is the field list for estimating where fields are used?

Tags: 8, entities

I am trying to locate all places where a particular field is used. I am trying to see especially which all Views have required the field.

I was planning to do a manual search using editor Find and grep. Then I came to know about the field list option under Reports -  /admin/reports/fields

It showed that the field is not being used by an views.

How accurate is this report? Can it be trusted blindly or do we need to complement it with an additional search?

Comment: Search in your exported config folder.

Answer (score 0):

As @leymannx mentioned I did a grep of the field in the config folder and although the field did come up in one of the Views on my Drupal site, it was mostly registered as a dependency and not used.  So it is safe to say that the field list is somewhat accurate.